# Dynamically Change Leaflet PopUp Background

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way to set the background image of a leaflet pop up dynamically?

I have multiple markers with popups, which all need a different background image. The filepaths for the images are being pulled from a database.

I have tried using jQuery to change the background property of the ".custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper" classes, but the change does not occur. When I type $(".leaflet-popup-content-wrapper") into the console, it returns an empty array which tells me that the current page cannot even see this class.

How can I dynamically apply a background image to each of the popups?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the popups' DOM elements with `marker.getPopup().getElement()` and work from there - see a [working example here](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/lop/1/edit?html,output).

> I have tried using jQuery to change the background property of the ".custom-popup .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper" classes, but the change does not occur.

First: you don't need jQuery. Second: wait until the popups are shown. Leaflet does not create DOM elements until things are actually added to a map. See [this example](https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/hosu/1/edit?html,console,output) for a practical demonstration.